# Is there a way to fix this Method to return the value?

Tags: java, methods, char

I built a Method that would allow me to send a double and return back as a char but the only thing that seems to register is my 'c' return. What am I doing wrong?

```
     public static void playOneGame () {

                double max = 100;
                double min = 1;
                char userInput;
                double guess = 50;
        userInput = getUserResponseToGuess(guess);
          
        while(userInput !='c') {
            
            if(userInput == 'h') { 
               min = guess; 
                guess= midPoint(min,max);
                
            }
                
            else if(userInput== 'l') 
            {
                    max = guess;
                    guess = midPoint(min,max);
            }
          else {
            System.out.println("Input must be  (h/l/c)");
            userInput = scnr.next().charAt(0);
          }
          }
    while (userInput == 'c')
{
    shouldPlayAgain();


    public static char getUserResponseToGuess(double guess) 
        {
            char input;
            
            System.out.println("Is it: "+ (int)guess +  "(h/l/c)");
             input = scnr.next().charAt(0);
            
             return input;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out and I guess I will answer my own question for anyone who may see this and has a similar question. I initialized the original input but that wont loop back again, so I had to initialize another userInput at the bottom of the loop Ex:

```
     userInput = getUserResponseToGuess(guess);
      
    while(userInput !='c') {
        
        if(userInput == 'h') { 
           min = guess; 
            guess= midPoint(min,max);
            
        }
            
        else if(userInput== 'l') 
        {
                max = guess;
                guess = midPoint(min,max);
        }
      else {
        System.out.println("Input must be  (h/l/c)");
        userInput = scnr.next().charAt(0);
      }
   **userInput = getUserResponseToGuess(guess);**
      }
```

It is right after the else Statement from the initial while loop.

```
  else {
        System.out.println("Input must be  (h/l/c)");
        userInput = scnr.next().charAt(0);
      }
   **userInput = getUserResponseToGuess(guess);**
      }
```